# Promises in Mongoose in recursive, returning issue

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongoose, promise

I'm struggling with promises with Mongoose because I am used to do synchronous programming.

**Context**

I have many categories. Each category have no or one parent category.
A knowledge is associated with a category.
I would like to create a tree with all categories with their sub-categories and knowledge(s).

[image]

Actually, it looks like a model with **directories** and **files**.
The expected output would be like a JSON :

```
[
    {"name": "cat0",
     "children": [{"name": know0}]
    },
    {"name": "cat1",
    ...
]
```

**Code**

I use a recursive way. I call the function with null (which get all roots categories), then the recursive call will apply on the sub-categories.

```
static findKnowledgeByCategory(query = null){


    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        CategoryModel.find({parent: query})
            .then((categories) => {
                console.log(query + ' : CategoryModel.find success');
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    console.log(query + ' : new Promise');
                    categories.forEach(cat => { // cat == { _id: ..., parent: ..., name: 'smthng' }
                        KnowledgeModel.find({category: cat._id})
                            .then((knowledges) => {
                                console.log(query + ' : KnowledgeModel.find success');
                                cat.knowledges = knowledges;
                                Model.findKnowledgeByCategory(cat._id)
                                    .then((categories) =>{
                                        cat.children = categories;
                                    });
                            })
                    })
                }).then(() => {
                    console.log(query + ' : Début resolve');
                    return resolve(categories);
                })
            })
            .catch((err) =>{
                console.log(err);
                return reject();
            } )
    });

}
```

I must return a promise with this code, because at a more global scope its resolve is used to return the tree in JSON.

**Global Scope**

```
findKnowledgeByCategory()
        .then((catAndKnow) => res.status(200).json(catAndKnow))
        .catch(err => Validation.handleError(res, 500, err));
```

There is no error displayed, but when I call the function, the server does not respond.

Notice it will never display "Début resolve"...
I'm using Node 6.11.2 so I can't use "await". 
Any idea would be appreciated. I apologize if my issue is not relevant. I think I don't manage well my promises but I don't have any clue.

Comment: That's a 6th level callback hell. You really need to break this code into smaller pieces, functions, or async/await blocks. Or use the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module. Because debugging that as it is now is the reason why it's called _hell_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the [promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). As your method calls (like `find`) already produce promises, you should return the promise chain you attach to those.

Secondly, keep your nesting flat: promises were invented for this reason, so instead of nesting `then` calls, return the promise to the outer chain as soon as you can, and chain a `then` call there.

Finally, when you create promises within a `forEach`, you'll need to combine those somehow into one promise. `Promise.all` is just the remedy for that. So instead of `forEach`, use `map` returning promises in the callback, and pass that result to `Promise.all`.

Here is how your code could look (not tested):

```
static findKnowledgeByCategory(query = null) {
    return CategoryModel.find({parent: query}).then((categories) => {
        console.log(query + ' : CategoryModel.find success');
        return Promise.all(categories.map(cat => {
            return KnowledgeModel.find({category: cat._id}).then((knowledges) => {
                console.log(query + ' : KnowledgeModel.find success');
                cat.knowledges = knowledges;
                return Model.findKnowledgeByCategory(cat._id);
            }).then((children) => {
                cat.children = children;
            });
        })).then(() => {
            console.log(query + ' : Début resolve');
            return categories;
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Looks like it does not enter in the then(children) but I think I can find by myself.

Comment: If execution does not get to that `then` callback, check that the `KnowledgeModel.find({category: cat._id})` promise maybe rejects instead of fulfills.  You could chain a `.catch` after that `then ((children)` to check that.

Comment: Indeed, I just noticed. Thanks.for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this part of the code:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(query + ' : new Promise');
    categories.forEach(cat => { 
        KnowledgeModel.find({category: cat._id})
            .then((knowledges) => {
                console.log(query + ' : KnowledgeModel.find success');
                cat.knowledges = knowledges;
                Model.findKnowledgeByCategory(cat._id)
                .then((categories) =>{
                    cat.children = categories;
                });
        })
    })
})
```

You are never calling `resolve` nor `reject` inside this promise so it is never resolved. Try to split your code into smaller functions returning promises and then arrange them together - it would be much easier to catch situations like this.

Comment: Thank you for responding. To explain this, I tried to put a resolve() after the forEach() bloc, but it is not what I want to. Because it will fulfill the promise although the loop is not finished yet. How to handle that (in other words, a synchronous process in a promise) ?

Comment: Also I tried without the "return" but without better results.

Comment: By using `category.forEach` you are iterating over each category and doing some queries for each of them. This means you should wait for all that queries to end. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all method. But first of all try to reorganize this big function into smaller ones and compose them together - it will make the code more readable.